# Modifying the main editor priority

Tags: metabox, editor, wp-editor

I want the main WordPress post editor to appear below some of my meta boxes (generated by Advanced Custom Fields).

I know there are the `add_meta_box()` and `remove_meta_box()` functions, however it'd be really awesome if I could just modify the editor meta box priority without having to remove and add it again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I'll first explain why @s_ha_dum's answer doesn't work for me.

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to add the extra meta boxes, the ones I need to appear above the WordPress editor.

@s_ha_dum pointed out that the WordPress editor is [hardcoded within the template](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L359), but I noticed it can be disabled by removing support for the editor. With this in mind I've disabled support for the editor, then added the code for the editor in a new meta box.

Et voila:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    remove_post_type_support('post', 'editor');
});

add_action('add_meta_boxes', function () {

    $screens = array('post');

    foreach ($screens as $screen) {

        add_meta_box(
            'moved_editor',
            'Moved Editor',
            'moved_editor_custom_box',
            $screen
        );

    }

});

function moved_editor_custom_box( $post ) {

    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

    ?>

        <style>

            #moved_editor {
                border: none;
            }

            #moved_editor h3 {
                display: none;
            }

            #moved_editor .inside {
                padding: 0;
            }

        </style>

        <div id="postdivrich" class="postarea">

            <?php wp_editor($post->post_content, 'content', array('dfw' => true, 'tabfocus_elements' => 'sample-permalink,post-preview', 'editor_height' => 360) ); ?>

            <table id="post-status-info" cellspacing="0">

                <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td id="wp-word-count"><?php printf( __( 'Word count: %s' ), '<span class="word-count">0</span>' ); ?></td>
                        <td class="autosave-info">

                            <span class="autosave-message">&nbsp;</span>

                                <?php if ( 'auto-draft' != $post->post_status ) : ?>

                                    <span id="last-edit">'

                                        <?php if ( $last_id = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_edit_last', true) ) : ?>

                                            <?php

                                                $last_user = get_userdata($last_id); 
                                                printf(__('Last edited by %1$s on %2$s at %3$s'), esc_html( $last_user->display_name ), mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_modified), mysql2date(get_option('time_format'), $post->post_modified));

                                            ?>

                                        <?php else : ?>

                                            <?php printf(__('Last edited on %1$s at %2$s'), mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $post->post_modified), mysql2date(get_option('time_format'), $post->post_modified)); ?>

                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    </span>

                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </td>

                        </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>

    <?
}
```

Comment: I would watch this carefully. There may be other consequences to removing editor support. I have never tried to remove it and then still use it in another box.

Comment: Yeah this was a concern I was trying to sidestep from the beginning, however it still appears to save and output the content... not sure what else it could cause problems with.

Comment: "...what else it could cause problems with..." -- I am not sure either, but it is possible that it could cause an issue somewhere. I'd have to really dig into the Core and see what that setting effects. Cautionary tale, that's all.

Comment: I'm might just do that... don't want this messing up. Many thanks, very helpful :-)

Answer (score 4):

The editor is [hard-coded into the form](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L359). It isn't inserted by `add_meta_box`.

There is a hook called `edit_form_after_title` which you should be able to use though.

### Proof of concept:

```
// use the action to create a place for your meta box
function add_before_editor($post) {
  global $post;
  do_meta_boxes('post', 'pre_editor', $post);
}
add_action('edit_form_after_title','add_before_editor');

// add a box the location just created
function test_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'generic_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Generic Title' ), // meta box title
        'generic_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'pre_editor', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );
}
function generic_cb($post) {
  var_dump($post);
  echo 'generic content';
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'test_box' );
```

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum, I'll take a look at this and get back to you :-)

Comment: so this would work perfectly is I were using my own custom meta boxes, however I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, of which doesn't have an option to put the editor box elsewhere. I'm about to post my own answer to this question, your answer helped me get there :-)