# How to add custom control to a page?

Tags: customization

I want to add a simple control to a page that allows the user to change the background.  Something like this:

[image: Custom Control]

Since there could be any number of pages and colors I thought it would be best to do it with a control, but not sure how.

Comment: You want a meta box, something like: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100487/modifying-the-main-editor-priority/100495#100495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great tutorial to do this very thing:
http://javatechig.com/wordpress/how-to-implement-color-picker-with-wordpress

```
<?php
// add the meta box
function wdm_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('wdm_sectionid', 'Post Background', 'wdm_meta_box_callback', 'post');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wdm_add_meta_box' );

// callback function that renders your meta-box on the admin pages
function wdm_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'wdm_meta_box', 'wdm_meta_box_nonce' );
    $color = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_bg', true );
?>
    <div class="custom_meta_box">
    <p>
    <input class="color-field" type="text" name="post_bg" value="<?php echo '#'.$color; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    </div>
<script>
    // Add WordPress's custom color picker to all inputs that have 'color-field' class
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
    $('.color-field').wpColorPicker();
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
<?php 
}

// save the user's meta-box input to the database
function wdm_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['wdm_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wdm_meta_box_nonce'], 'wdm_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_bg = ( isset( $_POST['post_bg'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['post_bg'] ) : '' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_bg', $post_bg );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wdm_save_meta_box_data' );

// enables use of wordpress's custom color picker
function wpse_80236_Colorpicker(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');
    //
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_80236_Colorpicker');
?>
```

If you need to get color code ids, simply add the following line of code in your functions.php file.

```
$post_background = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_bg', true );
echo $post_background // here is your color code
```

If you want this to work for a page instead of a post, replace `post` with `page` in the `wdm_add_meta_box()` function.